# Configure Kafka ordering service on Hyperledger Fabric network built with Hyperledger Composer

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am writing an application on Angular and I used the following Hyperledger Composer tutorial as a guide:

[Hyperledger Composer Developer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial)

Everything went great and I got the app running and understood how to interact with the API and make the queries. What I'm facing now is that I need to configure Kafka consensus on my Hyperledger Fabric network. I followed the following tutorial to install my Fabric network and environment:

[Hyperledger Composer Development Environment  Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools)

I'm trying to use this for configuring Kafka on my network but directories and files created using the above tutorial are different than the ones described on the following tutorial:

[Bringing up a Kafka-based Ordering Service](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/kafka.html)

So my question is, is it possible to configure Kafka-based ordering service on a network built using the Hyperledger Composer tutorials mentioned above? If yes, is there anyone out there who was done it successfully?